# Check my Latin: Note on Ovid’s use of the name Appias. (A fountain, a nymph, and a bunch of lawyers.)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, contemporary-latin, history, ovidius

Ovid uses the words *Appias* or *Appiades* on three occasions (Ars Amatoria 1.79-88 and 3.447-452; Remedia Amoris 659-660) to refer jokingly to the legal business conducted in the Forum of Julius Caesar.  Here is a note I wrote to elucidate this reference.  Check my Latin, please!

Annō circiter 311 a.C.n Appius Claudius Caecus cēnsor aquaeductum cōnstrūxit ut aqua in urbem indūcerētur, quae ab eō Appia aqua appellāta est.  Annīs plūrimīs praeteritīs Iūlius Caesar templum Venerī Genetrīcī dedicāvit in Forō Iūliō, in quō templō fōns reperiēbātur, ab Arcesilāō artifice celeberrimō sculpta, ē quā Appia aqua ēmicēbat, ita ut fōns ipsa Appias dēsignāta sit, quasi nympha fontis; Appiades erant imāginēs Concordiae, Minervae, Pācis, Veneris, et Vestae circā fontem sitae.  Forum Iūlium erat praetereā locus quem iūriscōnsultī frequentābant ut causās agerent.  Nāsō igitur Appiada nōmen ūsūrpātur ut ad iūs et lītēs et causās allūdat.